Achieving userManager user without tracking it

        public async Task<CreateSuperUserResponse> UpdateAdmin(AppUsers appuser)
        {
            // var userLog = await application.Users.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == appuser.Id);
            var user = await manager.FindByIdAsync(appuser.Id);
            if (user != null)
            {
                //Capture old values for audit trail
                var oldUser = new AppUsers
                {
                    Email = user.Email,
                    FullNames = user.FullNames,
                    IsActive = user.IsActive,
                    Role = (await manager.GetRolesAsync(user)).Select(role => new UserRole(role)).ToList()
                };

                user.Email = appuser.Email;
                user.FullName= appuser.FullName;
                user.PhoneNumber= appuser.PhoneNumber;

                var result = await manager.UpdateAsync(user);

using asp .net web api
How can I effectively track user updates without using tracking in Entity Framework? I'm using FindByIdAsync to fetch user entities and capturing old values from the database, but how can I log what specific updates users are making?

Do not post images of code, post formatted code.

"but how can I log what specific updates users are making?" - What do you mean by that, exactly?

Good day, so basically the user that im fetching from db already have updated values in memory and i cannot use AsNoTracking() on the manager to fetch the original values

Sorry but that really makes no sense to me. What are you trying to achieve here?

You could try compare the "olduser" and "newuser" using a method.
    public class Variance
    {
        public string Prop { get; set; }
        public object valA { get; set; }
        public object valB { get; set; }
    }

Then in the controller
        List<Variance> Compare(AppUser oldUser, AppUser newUser)
        {
            List<Variance> variances = new List<Variance>();
            var properties = oldUser.GetType().GetProperties();

            foreach (var property in properties)
            {
                Variance v = new Variance
                {
                    Prop = property.Name,
                    valA = property.GetValue(oldUser),
                    valB = property.GetValue(newUser)
                };

                if ((v.valB != null) &&(!Equals(v.valA, v.valB)))
                {
                    //There are some property we need to ignore when compare difference
                    if ((v.Prop != "EmailConfirmed")&& (v.Prop != "SecurityStamp") && (v.Prop != "ConcurrencyStamp") && (v.Prop != "LockoutEnabled"))
                    variances.Add(v);
                }

            }
            return variances;
        }

To use
        public async Task test (IdentityUser identityUser)
        {
            var user =await _userMnager.FindByIdAsync (identityUser.Id);
            if (user != null) 
            {
                List<Variance> differences = Compare(user,identityUser);
                foreach(var item in differences)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item.Prop+" changed from "+item.valA+" to "+item.valB);
                }
...

Test result

